# I am trying to make a jump button or a swipe up in my game that will only come up for mobile users

Tags: javascript, canvas

So my game is pretty like mario but in js canvas and It's compatible on both PC and mobile. I already got the left and right touch movements working but now i am just trying to make a jump event as well.

I tried doing:
`addEventListener('touchmove', e => {    player.velocity.y -= 15 })`

but it won't work because I am trying to make it only trigger when I swipe upwards.

Comment: Are you trying to detect a swipe-up gesture?

Answer (score 0):

To detect the swipe gesture you can listen to the touchstart and touchmove events and store the start and last position respectively.

then on the touchend event compare both positions to see if the user moved upwards (there is also the possibility that the user didn't move)

```js
const MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let startPosition;
let lastPosition;

const onDown = event => {
    startPosition = getTouchPosition(event);
    lastPosition = null;
};

const onMove = event => {
  lastPosition = getTouchPosition(event);
};

const onUp = event => {
    // didn't move
    if (! lastPosition) {
        return showMessage("DIDN'T MOVE");
    }

    var yDiff = Math.abs(startPosition.y - lastPosition.y);

    // didn't move enough to be considered a swipe
    if (yDiff < MIN_DISTANCE) {
        return showMessage('NOT A SWIPE');
    }

    if (startPosition.y > lastPosition.y) {
        showMessage('SWIPE UP')
    } else {
        showMessage('SWIPE DOWN');
    }    
};

// Touch
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', onDown);
canvas.addEventListener('touchend', onUp);
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', onMove);

// Mouse
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onDown);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMove)
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onUp);

function showMessage(text) {
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    ctx.font = '20px bold Arial';
    ctx.fillText(text, 100, 100);
}

function getTouchPosition(event) {
    if (! event.touches) {
      return {
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY
      }
    }

    return {
        x: event.touches[0].clientX,
        y: event.touches[0].clientY
    };
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="500"></canvas>
```